# How To Resolve The Type Name 'Apis' does not exist in the type 'Google' when appropriate references are installed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-api

I've been working on an asp.net c# website for the past two years utilizing Google Api's.  I opened Visual Studio earlier this week and pages that were compiled and are currently live in production, are now indicating errors in regards to the Google Api's, especially for token responses.  There are other pages that are using the same exact code, and are not generating any errors.  What could be causing VS to indicate these errors?

As I mentioned, nothing has changed.  The pages were compiled a few weeks ago and are currently running on our production website.

When I noticed the errors upon loading the project, I updated all the Google packages to the latest version hoping it would clear up the issue, alas to no avail.

I even took the code that I have written on other pages that are not generating errors that complete the same task and pasted it into the page and the error still occurs.

Lastly, I went into the cache for Visual Studio and cleared that as well and the problem still persists.

These declarations are included on pages that work and don't work:

```
using Google.Apis;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows;
using Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1;
using Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
```

Code block that causes the error:

```
var token = new Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse()
{
  AccessToken = valid_token,  
  TokenType = "Bearer",
  ExpiresInSeconds = 3600,
  RefreshToken = refresh_token 
};
```

Visual Studio indicates the following error in the above code:

*The type name 'Apis' does not exist in the type 'Google'*

As I mentioned earlier, I have the EXACT same declaration on other pages and the error is not occurring on those pages.

Any ideas as to what is causing this?

Comment: Is there a different declaration for `Google` in the file which is failing? Try right clicking on it in Visual Studio and selecting "Go to definition", does it go to the right place?

Comment: Doug, thank you!  Someone put a file in the SVN titled Google, which caused the issue.  I didn't know you can use the Go to definition in VS.  Thanks again!

Comment: No problem! :-)